# PHP and PDO dynamic parameter binding

Tags: php, pdo

I'm trying to fix this butchered bit of code - as you might have guessed, I'm cocking up the bind param syntax. In fact, I'm not even sure what I'm trying to do is even possible. Here's the class method...

```
/***
*
* @select values from table
*
* @access public
*
* @param string $table The name of the table
*
* @param array $fieldlist Fields to return in results, defaults null
*
* @param array $criteria Search criteria by keyed by fieldname
*
* @param int $limit Limit of records to return, defaults 10
*
* @return Array on success or throw PDOException on failure
*
*/
public function dbSearch($table, $fieldList = null, $criteria = null, $limit = 10)
{
    // setup $this->db to point to a PDO instance
    $this->conn();

    // build fieldlist
    if( is_null($fieldList) OR !is_array($fieldList) OR count($fieldList) == 0) {
        $returnFields = '*';
    } else {
        $returnFields = "'".implode("', '", $fieldList)."'";
    }

    // build criteria
    if( is_null($criteria) OR !is_array($criteria) OR count($criteria) == 0) {
        $whereClause = '';
    } else {
        $whereClause = array();
        foreach ($criteria as $key => $value){
           $bind_name    = 'bind_'.$key; //generate a name for bind1, bind2, bind3...
           $$bind_name   = $value; //create a variable with this name with value in it
           $bind_names[] = & $$bind_name; //put a link to this variable in array
           $whereClause[] = "'$key' = :$bind_name";
        }
        $whereClause = count($whereClause) > 0 ? ' WHERE '.implode( ' AND ' , $whereClause ) : '';
    }

    $sql = "SELECT $returnFields FROM '$table' $whereClause LIMIT $limit"; 

    $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);

    if( $whereClause != '') {
        call_user_func_array(array(&$stmt, 'bindParam'), $bind_names);
    }

    $stmt->execute();
    return $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```

... which at some point I want to call using something along these lines...

```
// look for users in database...
$user_recs = $crud->dbSearch('user', array('user_name'), array('user_name'=> $_POST['username']));
$users = $user_recs->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

How bonkers is this? Is it possible? Do I need to pass in the param types as well somehow? Any help gratefully received!

Comment: It made me to the dictionary for the bonkers

Comment: Could you elaborate what is the problem exactly? Of course you can bind dynamic parameters, you can use [bindParam()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php), and of course you need to pass the datatype of the parameters, or at least *guess* it (but since you are passing the values, it's effortless to pass the types as well).

Comment: it is possible but personally I hate such query builders a lot. You are getting the same SQL in the end, but tortured and bound.

Comment: And as Your Common Sense wrote, such query builders usually make more harm than anything. Why don't you store all your queries in a separate and clean file (maybe a dedicated Class, also static if you like) where you can define queries, parameters and datatypes. Then in your call, it will be enough to pass an identifier for the desired query and an array containing the values for the parameters. Much cleaner, really.

Comment: Well, you're a cheerful bunch, I must say ;-) I've been asked by the client to ensure that all SQL queries use bound params, via PDO, that's why. Personally, yes, I would do it another way. So, could we leave aside the critiques. Ta.

Comment: What's wrong with my example which is **actually using bound parameters** then? Via PDO, mind you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, the problem was using bound parameters as opposed to bound values... doh!

Given an SQL statement and some values in an associative array, e.g.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM event
        WHERE eventdate >= :from 
        AND eventdate <= :until 
        AND ( user_name LIKE :st OR site_name LIKE :st )
        ORDER BY eventdate, start_time LIMIT 100";

$values = array( 'st'    => '%'.$searchterm.'%',
                 'from'  => $fromdate,
                 'until' => $untildate, );
```

then this class method ( but it could easily by a plain function) did the trick:

```
    public function dbBoundQuery($sql, $values, $types = false) {
        $this->conn();

        $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);

        foreach($values as $key => $value) {
            if($types) {
                $stmt->bindValue(":$key",$value,$types[$key]);
            } else {
                if(is_int($value))        { $param = PDO::PARAM_INT; }
                elseif(is_bool($value))   { $param = PDO::PARAM_BOOL; }
                elseif(is_null($value))   { $param = PDO::PARAM_NULL; }
                elseif(is_string($value)) { $param = PDO::PARAM_STR; }
                else { $param = FALSE;}

                if($param) $stmt->bindValue(":$key",$value,$param);
            }
        }

        $stmt->execute();
        return $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }
```

Hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 1):

I really don't understand how this function is better than conventional

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT user_name FROM user WHERE user_name = ?");
$stmt->execute($_POST['username']);
$users = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

Mind you,

- it keeps your query **flexible**. `LIMIT ?,?` is possible
- it keeps your query **readable**. Almost natural English of SQL stays in place. You **still** can tell what does your query do, without the need of learning some brain-damaging language. As a side effect, any other developer can comprehend this code too.

Comment: Again, not my choice. Client dictat.

Comment: What? What kind of client you have? Are you certainly sure he understands a single word in your program?

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are quite a few things that can go wrong with the code.

For once, I don't see any `AND` / `OR` between `WHERE` clauses - which is probably why it doesn't work.

Secondly, it doesn't allow you to use SQL functions. Let's say you need to write a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date_added) < ...;
```

You get the idea.

I would suggest to either use an existing ORM ([Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/), [Propel](http://propelorm.org/), etc), or stick to PDO.

Here is an example of how I would use PDO for a User class:

```
class User
{

 protected $data;
 public function __get($key) {
      return $this->data[$key];
 }
 public function __set($key, $value) {
     $this->data[$key] = $value;
 }
/**
 * @param $value
 * @param $field
 * @return $this
 */
public function loadBy($value, $field)
{
    $db = DbFactory::getInstance();
    $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE $field = :$field LIMIT 1";
    $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute(array(":$field" => $value));
    $result = $stmt->fetch();

    foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
        $this->$key = $value;
    }

    return $this;
}
}
```

You can create such functions for your entities, this you will have functions that are specialized, and efficient in what they do, and that are easy to test.

**PS:**
Ignore the issue that appears when you have a field named `data` :)

Comment: Point taken re booleans - AND is what's needed and I'll amend. There are no fields named data. ;-) So I'll ignore it. Thanks.